# how to use dtree javascript tree

Tags: javascript, treeview

I want to turn an ordinary nested  list, into a collapsable tree like structure such as [dtree](http://www.destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/). I have the list right now as html with nested  tags, I want to implement this sort of tree but need some steps on how to do it. The site doesn't do a very good job at explaining it.

Thanks!

tariq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code to use after you have included the proper javascript files that dtree provides:

```
//Create the tree
d = new dTree('d');

//Add a node and keep adding the rest of the nodes until they are all in there
d.add(
      1, //Unique id for the node
      -1, //Parent node -- use -1 for root
      'My node', //Text Label for the node 
      'node.html', //Url for the node
      'node title', //Title for the node
      'mainframe', //Target for the node when opening the url
      'img/musicfolder.gif' //Icon image. Uses default if not specified
      'img/musicfolderOpen.gif' //Open Icon image. Uses default if not specified
      true //Whether the node is open or not (optional)
     );

//write the node to the html page
document.write(d);
```

I recommend using an easier javascript tree like 'Simple Tree Menu' which is easier to set up. Simple Tree Menu can be found here:

http://www.generalflows.com/www/software#sys/SimpleTreeMenuView

The js can be downloaded here:

http://www.generalflows.com/js/lib/jquery/jquery-simpleTreeMenu-1.0.0.js

Comment: how do you download this one?

Comment: so I download this js and import it in the html file, then I create the nested listed using <ul> <li> tags?  then call the js using jQuery('#myMenuTree').simpleMenuTree(); command?

Comment: That is correct. Also make sure your ul has the id of 'myMenuTree' like so: <ul id="myMenuTree">

Comment: this is not working, do I haveto call the jQuery('#myMenuTree').simpleMenuTree(); after the nested list?

Comment: jquery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#myMenuTree').simpleMenuTree();
});